# Telnet and Encoding in Python

Tags: python, telnet

This question is probably simple but so far I have not been able to find a solution anywhere. Basically, the following code is supposed to connect to a host, take a command, and print everything the host returns.

```
import telnetlib
import time

HOST = input("IP Address: ")
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, port = 23, timeout = 20)
time.sleep(10)
command = input("Enter command: ")
command.encode('utf-8')
tn.write(b"\n".join(command))
ret1 = tn.read_eager()
print(ret1)

print("Success!")
tn.close()
```

However, no matter what I try I keep on getting the same error:

```
C:\Python34>call python34 telnet_test.py
IP Address: 10.20.249.64
Enter command: 001 rq version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telnet_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    tn.write(b"\n".join(command))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

I've tried other solutions based on similar questions I looked up but none of them seemed to work specifically here, I always end up getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Python 2 and not 3.
I didn't mess about with any sort of encoding and it worked. Basically, my code was as follows:

```
HOST = input("IP Address: ")
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, port = 23, timeout = 20)
time.sleep(10)
command = input("Enter command: ")
tn.write(command + "\r\n")
ret1 = tn.read_eager()
print(ret1)
```

I will point out these 3 things:
 1. the encode function returns the encoded version of the string, it does't alter the string itself, so if you wish to change the command variable, you should use `command = command.encode("utf-8")`.
 2. I used `\r\n`, since this is a Windows machine.
 3. Also, I am not sure if this is what you meant to do, but your `join` was inserting a `\n` between every single character in your command string.

**EDIT 24.07.15** Since you are using Python 3, I downloaded Python 3 and gave it another go. Here's a code that worked for me:

```
HOST = input("IP Address: ")
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, port = 23, timeout = 20)
time.sleep(10)
command = input("Enter command: ") + "\r\n"
tn.write(command.encode('utf-8'))
ret1 = tn.read_eager()
print(ret1)
```

The reason you received this error, is because you didn't receive `encode`'s return value back into the `command` variable, so it stayed unaltered. Therefore, when you called `write` with `command`, it still received a string, which it was not expecting.
2 side notes - you need to use `"\r\n"`, not just `"\n"`, assuming you're using a Windows telnet server, though `"\n"` is fine with UNIX systems; I don't know the configuration of your telnet server, but, by default, they require authentication, so there's a chance you will have to enter credentials before entering a command.

Comment: OP is using Python 3.

Comment: I should've specified, I'm using Python 3. Your code gives me the error "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes", stemming from the line "command = input("Enter command: ")"

Comment: Looks like it worked, thanks. Now my only problem is that it only returns b' ' instead of any actual text but I think I can figure that out, it might be something on the server's end.